# eclipse rcp: key binding with toolitem

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a toolbar in my eclipse rcp application, it contains three buttons,

1. home button: go to home page
2. back button: go to previous page
3. forward button: go to next page

the code create them :

```
ToolBar tb = new ToolBar(toolBarComp, SWT.NONE);
        fd = new FormData();
        fd.right = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
        tb.setLayoutData(fd);

        homeBtn = new ToolItem(tb, SWT.PUSH);
        homeBtn.setImage(ResourceManager.getImage(ResourceClass.class, "home.png"));
        homeBtn.setToolTipText("返回主页");

        backBtn = new ToolItem(tb, SWT.PUSH);
        backBtn.setImage(ResourceManager.getImage(ResourceClass.class, "back.png"));
        backBtn.setToolTipText("返回至上一页");
        backBtn.setEnabled(false);
        backBtn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter(){

            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                CompositePageRender.this.controler.goBack();
            }

        });

        forwardBtn = new ToolItem(tb, SWT.PUSH);
        forwardBtn.setImage(ResourceManager.getImage(ResourceClass.class, "forward.png"));
        forwardBtn.setToolTipText("前进至下一页");
        forwardBtn.setEnabled(false);
        forwardBtn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter(){

            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                CompositePageRender.this.controler.goFroward();
            }

        });
```

I wan to bind ALT+H with the home button, is that possible ? how to do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you would like to accomplish. Does "_I wan to bind ALT-H with the home button_" mean, that you would like the action of the home button to be executed when the user does ALT-H?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within an SWT application you can use mnemonics to simulate pressing Buttons.

But if you mean an RCP application with ToolItems in a toolbar, you need to use the command framework to use keybindings.

You define a command, and then use a handle to implement the behaviour.  Then you have both your ToolItem and keybinding <kbd>ALT+H</kbd> point to the same command.

See [Workbench extension points using Commands](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_cmd.htm) for more information.

Comment: do you mean, invoke the command handler in the button listener?

Comment: If you have a toolbar and a `ToolBarManager`, then you use `CommandContributionItems` to call the command from the tool item.  If you are just using tool items and selection listeners, then you use the `org.eclipse.ui.handlers.IHandlerService` to execute the command.